# javascript inheritance. inherit object and methods from another class

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I was following a video tutorial on JS inheritance, I stuck on the last 2 line of code below :

[image: http://i.imgur.com/A9DDMHL.jpg]

assume above there is an `Animal` class, and we want to use the properties and methods.

I seem to get the second last : `Cat.prototype = new Animal()`. is it saying assigning a new animal object to cat's prototype? but I cannot understand the last line of code.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend reading this article

- [Understanding JavaScript Object Creation Patterns](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687093/Understanding-JavaScript-Object-Creation-Patterns)

The `prototype` property provides the object that methods and properties will be inherited from when you create an object via the `Cat` constructor function. Whereas `constructor` is nothing more than a regular property which is typically used to identify the constructor function used to create an object.

Comment: I see! you cant do new Cat() yet because if we do so, we missed all the  properties and methods from animal. right?

Comment: If you read the reference article, you will find that the constructor property doesn't perform any function, you can do what you like with it!

Answer (score 0):

`Cat.prototype = new Animal()` means that the `Cat` class is inheriting the methods and properties of the `Animal` class, most likely because `Cat` is an `Animal`, and reusing methods from the `Animal` class in `Cat` class wastes time.

`Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat` is just making the constructor of the `Cat` class the constructor you just made above for all `Cat` objects.

Comment: This is just totally wrong. Stop speaking about class and superclass for a non class oriented language.

Comment: Look at this: http://www.codecademy.com/courses/objects-ii/3/3?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661

Comment: Look at this: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf   4.2.1 : [ECMAScript does not use classes such as those in C++, Smalltalk, or Java]  even if a teenager wrote the opposite on a public wiki.

Comment: This question is about javascript, not ECMAScript.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, JavaScript is not a class based language. It doesn't know about the concept of classes, but it knows about objects and the [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) and with those two components, we can simulate class-like behavior and implement inheritance.

But since this all is kind of a workaround, we sometimes have to put extra effort in it, in order to make it work. And this is where your last line `Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat` comes in.

The `prototype` property of every function has a property called `constructor` which points to the function itself. So when you use the function as a constructor, the internal `[[prototype]]` object has the `constructor` property as well.

```
function Cat() {
}

var cat = new Cat();
console.log(Cat.prototype.constructor); //Cat
console.log(cat.constructor); //Cat
```

But, if you apply your inheritance pattern, you override the complete `prototype` property of `Cat` with all its properties, including the `constructor` property.

```
function Cat() {
}

Cat.prototype = new Animal();

var cat = new Cat();
console.log(Cat.prototype.constructor); //Animal
console.log(cat.constructor); //Animal
```

To fix this, we have to set the `constructor` property manually:

```
function Cat() {
}

Cat.prototype = new Animal();
Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;

var cat = new Cat();
console.log(Cat.prototype.constructor); //Cat
console.log(cat.constructor); //Cat
```